# USB mouse stops working after unplugging the power cord in Ubuntu laptop

Tags: mouse

I have been using Ubuntu 11.04 for almost a month without any issue. But now Its showing a weird behavior. When I unplug the power cord from my laptop running Ubuntu 11.04, the external USB mouse stops working even if the laptop is fully charged. Again after plugging the power cord it starts working. Please help what to do.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging it and plugging it back in that works for me. Don't know why it happens but a quick solution is good enough for me. I think it's because of the power settings but wouldn't be a hundred percent sure unless I actually dug deeper. Hope this works.

Comment: I unplugged and then plugged. I rebooted the system thrice but to no use. :(

Comment: have you made and progress on this? Can you provide any more information? Can you verify this issue is specific to 11.04? Have you tried other USB mouse devices? Please update your question so we can be of more help.

Comment: Is there any update on this?